# How to increase base size of one docker container

Tags: docker

I have tried to increase default size of docker container using --storage-opt option and it works.

But in my case, I have one container which needs more disk space than other containers. so I am interested in how do I configure base size per container.

```
docker details:
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 21.47 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 1.776 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 49.43 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 3.228 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.144 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [runtime constraints on resources¶](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-constraints-on-resources) for [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run) is only for cpu, memory and IO, not yet for disk space.

You would need a [device mapper](https://github.com/snitm/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/README.md) (not yet implemented) or at least a [container data volume manager like flocker](https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/) (available) to try and set limits per container (or [at least container cluster](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/gettinginvolved/cluster-setup.html#adding-containers-and-datasets)).

But [as mentioned in 2013](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/471#issuecomment-16979828), storage limits are not straightforward, as cgroups don't have a hook for that.

Answer (score 0):

Its a old post but I would like to post the solution which I found.

```
sed -i '/STORAGE_OPTIONS=/s/$/"--storage-opt dm.basesize=20G"/' /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
```

you need to change STORAGE_OPTION under /etc/sysconfig/docker_storage to change basesize and then restart docker to take this in effect.